# Gamma Function Removable Singularity

Tags: gamma-function

So apparently:

```
xΓ(x) = Γ(x+1)
```

But when I plug them both into Mac's Grapher, Γ(x+1) is defined at 0 (it equals 1), whereas xΓ(x) is not. Can I define 0 * Γ(0) to be 1 via analytic continuation?

The specific function that I am looking at is this one:

```
f(x) = Γ(x+2) / xΓ(x)
```

which I want to evaluate to 1 for x = 0. As I understand it, the expansion looks like this:

```
(x+1)(x)(x-1)(x-2)... / (x)(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)... = (x+1)
```

Is it fair to say that xΓ(x) = 1 when x = 0 in this case?

Thanks you guys!

Comment: In the sense of a limit as $x\to 0$, yes. Also note that since $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$ for integer $n$, that that's the same as saying that $0!=\Gamma(1)=1$ which is conventional.

Comment: $\Gamma(x)\sim\dfrac1{x}-\gamma~$ for $~x\to0$, where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Mascheroni_constant).

Comment: note that $\Gamma$ has a pole at $0$ of order $1$, so that this is traditionally how one works in analytic continuation.